# Python sort list based on value in list, in list

Tags: python-3.x

How would i sort this list, based on the integer inside the 2nd list?

```
import random

l= []

for i in range(10):
    l.append(['xyz', random.randint(1,100)])


print(l)
```

Thank you!

Comment: (There's no difference here between sorting a list of tuples and a list of lists, and so the answers to the linked question work without modification.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [13]: l.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

In [14]: l
Out[14]: 
[['xyz', 6],
 ['xyz', 7],
 ['xyz', 17],
 ['xyz', 41],
 ['xyz', 52],
 ['xyz', 54],
 ['xyz', 62],
 ['xyz', 66],
 ['xyz', 68],
 ['xyz', 69]]
```

Comment: `l.sort()` worked fine for me...